# How can I display this data into dynamic table in react-native instead of function map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
 {this.state.users.map(
 user=><View key={Math.random()*10} >
     <View><Text> Name : {user.name_teacher}</Text></View>
     <View><Text> Username : {user.username}</Text></View>      
 </View>

)}
```

i want to display this data in table dynamic in react-native

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please see [ask] and revise to add detail.

Comment: And what is the problem you have?

Comment: i want to display data in dynamic table

Comment: So why don't we see table markup?

Comment: i am researched for table but i don't found